# SharePoint 2007 Site usage report has random user who has never accessed site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I was hoping someone could shed some light on a current issue I'm facing.  A user is concerned because they have looked at the Site Usage Report for their SharePoint 2007 team-site and seen an other user in the 'Top Users for past 30 days' list.  This other user doesn't and has never had access to the site.

Anyone experienced something similar?  I know SP2007 site usage reports are a bit flaky, but is there an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have faced this kind of scenario in our SharePoint 2007 environment. One of the users did not have permission to access the SharePoint site. Whenever he tried to access the specific site, SharePoint will automatically redirect the user to AccessDenied.aspx page. In this case, SharePoint considers the redirected error page in his visit count and also included in the total hits count.

This could be a reason for the site visit counts for the specific user. The following link may help you to trace the user activities in Site Usage Report in SharePoint site.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20512.usage-reporting-in-sharepoint-wss-v3-and-moss.aspx